# What do you call someone who obsessively thinks they are sick?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a single word in English to describe someone who is too worried about their health and even thinks they are sick, thus, taking frequent clinical tests or taking too much predictive medication,etc.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The word is **hypochondriac** and they suffer from *hypochondria.*

> *noun*
> A person who is abnormally anxious about their health.
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hypochondriac)

ODO also gives the explanation of using *hypo-* ("under") rather than *hyper-* ("over") which one might expect if someone is overly anxious about something:

> late Middle English: via late Latin from Greek *hupokhondria,* denoting the soft body area below the ribs, from *hupo* 'under' + *khondros* 'sternal cartilage'. Melancholy was originally thought to arise from the liver, gall bladder, spleen, etc..

Comment: There is also ["Münchausen syndrome"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCnchausen_syndrome), where the individual actually fakes illness, sometimes to the extent of poisoning or injuring themselves to produce the appropriate symptoms.  And then there's "Münchausen syndrome by proxy", where a person does things to make another person ill (usually a parent to a child) out of some need for attention or sympathy.

Comment: And "malingering" is a term applied (especially in the military) to feigning illness to avoid school, work, etc, or for other fraudulent purposes.

Comment: Wikipedia article on [hypochondirasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypochondriasis).

Answer (score 9):

Hypochondriac would seem to fit the bill.

Comment: +1, The original *Greek hypochondriakos* referred to the region of the abdomen, an area that ancient doctors believed to be the seat of misery or melancholia

Comment: @MystiSinha the word is _hypochondrios_ and the region of the abdomen you're referring to would be either one of the right or left upper quadrant (RUQ/LUQ). The RUQ - called _dexiòn hypochòndrion_ - is where the liver, gallbladder and bile duct are located. The LUQ - called _aristeròn hypochòndrion_ - hosts the stomach and pancreas.

Comment: Note also that melancholia really means "black bile" - further confirming the close relationship that the Greeks believed existed between liver, gall bladder, and sense of well being.

Answer (score 4):

You call them a hypochondriac. A similar term is **[valetudinarian](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/valetudinarian)**:

> A person who is unduly anxious about their health.

It usually refers to people who really are frail but fuss about it so obsessively that they avoid actually getting sick. [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/valetudinarian) puts it better:

> A sickly or weak person, especially one who is constantly and morbidly
>   concerned with his or her health.

If you wanted to give a hypochondriac the benefit of the doubt, or just humour them, this would be a less pejorative word. See [World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-val1.htm) for a good description with examples. In Jane Austen's novel [Emma](http://www.pemberley.com/etext/Emma/chapter3.htm), the heroine's father Mr Woodhouse is a classic valetudinarian.

The word is from Latin *valetudinarius* = in ill health.